# Does a late reference letter to UWaterloo accepted?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter, university

One of my referees had to take an emergency leave because of a family death and because of that she would not be able to complete the recommendation to University of Waterloo(for MDSAI program) by end of deadline. She has informed me that she could complete the recommendation 2 days later from the deadline but the university website mentions that the reference needs to be submitted by deadline. Can this cause an issue and get my application rejected?

Comment: A late LOR will not get you rejected, no. Whether it will be read is a different story.

Comment: @Azor If N letters are required, having only N-1 can very well get you rejected on formal grounds.  (I don't know about Waterloo.)  Otherwise, why even ask for N letters, and not state "Every applicant can submit any number of LoRs, as they see fit."?

Answer (score 0):

This question can probably be best answered by the MSDAI's point of contact. You can find their contact information here: https://uwaterloo.ca/graduate-studies-postdoctoral-affairs/future-students/programs/data-science-and-artificial-intelligence-mdsai-co-op